# Как добавить несколько наименований в одну метку на Яндекс Карте?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карта-api

Есть код добавления меток товаров на карту в карточке товара и на карту на главной странице. Таким образом на главной выводятся в карте все товары, а в карточке товара на карте также все товары, но центрируется по выбранному товару.

У нескольких товаров могут быть одинаковые координаты и в метке отображается только 1 товар, как сделать, чтобы в метке отображались несколько товаров в балуне, например списком или ещё как, если у них совпадают координаты? Координаты берём из полей ACF.

```js
// Функция для вставки скрипта на главной странице
function add_map_script_to_home_page() {
    if (is_front_page()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('display-map-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

        // Получить список всех товаров WooCommerce
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );

        $products = new WP_Query($args);

        // Получить координаты и адрес для каждого товара
        $product_data = array();
        while ($products->have_posts()) {
            $products->the_post();
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $coordinates = get_field('coordinates', $product_id);
            $address = get_field('address', $product_id);

            if ($coordinates && $address) {
                $product_data[] = array(
                    'coordinates' => $coordinates,
                    'address' => $address,
          'productURL' => get_permalink($product_id) // Добавляем URL карточки товара
                );
            }
        }

        wp_reset_query();

        wp_localize_script('display-map-script', 'productData', $product_data);
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_map_script_to_home_page');
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (typeof ymaps === 'undefined') {
        // Если Yandex Maps API еще не загружено, загрузим его
        $.getScript('https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY&lang=ru_RU', function() {
            ymaps.ready(initMap);
        });
    } else {
        ymaps.ready(initMap);
    }

    function initMap() {
        var productData = window.productData;
        var map = new ymaps.Map('main-map', {
            center: [59.938784, 30.314997], // Начальные координаты центра карты
            zoom: 12
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < productData.length; i++) {
            var coordinates = productData[i].coordinates.split(',');
            var latitude = parseFloat(coordinates[0]);
            var longitude = parseFloat(coordinates[1]);
            var address = productData[i].address;

            var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([latitude, longitude], {
        balloonContent: address + '<br><a href="' + productData[i].productURL + '">Подробнее</a>'
      }, {
        preset: 'islands#blueDotIcon',
        maxWidth: 300
      });

            map.geoObjects.add(placemark);

            // Добавляем обработчик события клика для открытия балуна
            placemark.events.add('tap', function (e) {
        var target = e.get('target');
        if (target.balloon.isOpen()) {
          target.balloon.close();
        } else {
          target.balloon.open();
        }
      });

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Вроде как у вас масса точек, объединение которых — прямая задача кластеризатора. И он всю информацию по близкорасположенным меткам может в кучу собрать. Разве нет?